# How to fix this SQL Server error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
case 
   when proj.country_name = 'UK' 
      then proj.region = 'NE'
   when proj.Country_Name = 'Belgium' or proj.Country_Name = 'Germany' or proj.Country_Name = 'Netherlands' 
      then proj.region = 'CE'
   when proj.Country_Name = 'Spain' or proj.Country_Name = 'France' or proj.Country_Name = 'Italy' 
      then proj.region = 'SE'
   else proj.region
end as Region_NCC,
```

Thanks

Comment: Read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is invalid syntax `case` expression doesn't return value with column name :

```
case when proj.country_name = 'UK' then 'NE'
     when proj.Country_Name in ('Belgium', 'Germany', 'Netherlands') then 'CE'
     when proj.Country_Name in ('Spain','France', 'Italy') then 'SE' 
     else proj.region
end as Region_NCC
```

I have used `IN` clause instead of strange `OR` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when structure

```
   CASE expression
        WHEN condition1 THEN result1
        WHEN condition2 THEN result2
       ...
        WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
        ELSE result
      END
```

For your case you did mistake in  `then` clause it would be just  `then` `'NE'`
so complete condition will be below

```
case when proj.country_name = 'UK' then  'NE'
      when proj.Country_Name = 'Belgium' 
      or proj.Country_Name = 'Germany' 
      or proj.Country_Name = 'Netherlands' 
     then  'CE'
     when proj.Country_Name = 'Spain' 
     or proj.Country_Name = 'France' 
     or proj.Country_Name = 'Italy' 
    then  'SE'
     else proj.region
     end as Region_NCC
```